# Как можно передать значения из БД в json файл для занесения их в input-field'ы

Tags: javascript, java, база-данных, json

Пишу дипломную работу с напарником. Он на Java, я на JS. Необходимо в мои input-field'ы занести данные из его бд. Нигде конкретики не нашёл, но единственное, что увидел, якобы можно сделать так, чтобы напарник передавал данные (из бд) в json файлик, который был бы доступен мне для вывода данных оттуда.

Ещё было что-то про REST api, но я впервые с этим сталкиваюсь. Если действительно это может помочь, то расскажите, пожалуйста, поподробнее, что она позволяет делать.

Comment: Подключаешь библиотеку через npm, которая называется axios. Отправляешь другу запрос на получение данных, дожидаешься ответа от сервера и вуа-ля работаешь с объектом. Дальше пихай что хочешь и куда хочешь. Добро пожаловать в мир REST API

Comment: Правильно, смотрите в сторону REST api. Читайте, гуглите.